# How do you add a link to Label text in Xaml?

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, app.xaml

I have a xaml mobile project with a label inside a scroll view. In the text of the label I want to link to another xaml page in my app. How would I call a function I'm my code behind when this text is clicked? "Sign up for free!"

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Mobile.Views.Welcome"
             Title="Welcome!!!!">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Image Source="(iOS: ImageSource.FromFile('Logo.png'), Android: ImageSource.FromFile('Logo.png'), WinPhone: ImageSource.FromFile('Images/Logo.png'))" />
    <ScrollView Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="Center">
      <Label Font="15"  HorizontalOptions="Center">
       With your free account you can: 
        Search Colleges, College programs and careers. 

        Use out interest profiler to get a personalized list of careers that may interest you. Take a survey to find career clusters that are in line with your interests. 

        Store your favorite careers, colleges, programs, and more in your personal locker.

        Yes, I want to do this! Sign up for free!</Label>
    </ScrollView>
    <Button Grid.Row="2" BackgroundColor="Blue" Text="Log In" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" ></Button>
    <Button Grid.Row="3" BackgroundColor="Aqua" Text="Browse as Guest" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold"></Button>
 </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Sounds like what you actually want is a `RichTextBlock` with a `HyperlinkButton` in an `InlineUIContainer` like shown [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/063429b8-06d5-4195-a88d-2ca2e88d7de8/inline-hyperlinkbutton?forum=winappswithnativecode).

Comment: You probably have the answer by now, so... How did you do it?